# How to make a ribbon shaped UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am trying to create a ribbon shaped `UILabel` that looks like the image below using iOS in Objective C. The label is in each cell, which has its own view.

[image]

Comment: Use UIBezierPath to create a shape.

Comment: follow graphic design trick

Answer (score 0):

[image: See the screenshot attached, I gave color to UIView to identify it.]Here is the solution for you.

1. Create a square shaped UIView at the right edge of your UILabel of same height as your UILabel and set the constraints.
2. Give the Class name of that UIView as "TriangleView"

3.Then create an outlet for that view, which corresponds to "TriangleView"

Below is the "TriangleView" class code.

```
#import "TriangleView.h"

@implementation TriangleView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint   (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  // top left
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));  // mid right
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));  // bottom left
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}

@end
```

Comment: can you translate this to objective c? Thank you!